# Assigning NaN to -1 after performing StandardScaler

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I want to **StandardScaler** (Through SK learn) certain DataFrame, which contains a lot of **NaN** values and after performing this scaler shift I want to assign all `NaN` to -1. How this is possible as we know that StandardScaler doesn't work with NaN values?

If there is any other solution (Which is not dependent on **Scikit Learn**) also please mention that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(values_to_scale.values))
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not exactly that simple to deal with NaN values. It requires analyses of the data before taking any further step to deal with the NaN values. There are various ways you can deal with these missing values (the following is not an exhaustive list):

- **Ignore missing values altogther** : the problem with this approach is that the missing rows might contain important information in other columns and ignoring them would lead to incomplete analyses
- **Replace them with another value** : this one of the commonly used approaches, but the choice of the value that you will use to replace will affect your overall analysis. You could replace them with say mean, or say a placeholder value (like -1) which you know never occurs throughout the column.
- **Using regression to substitute the values**
- **Using KNN to substitue values **

You can take a look at the following links, to get a more better idea

- [Handling missing data](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-handle-missing-data-8646b18db0d4)
- [7 ways of handling missing data](https://measuringu.com/handle-missing-data/)
- [A guide to data exploaration](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/guide-data-exploration/)
- [Imputing missing values in Python](http://www.stephacking.com/handle-missing-data-imputer-python/)

Additionaly you can take a look at the [official sklearn documentation for imputing missing values](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/impute.html).

**Update** : You can ignore the NaN values while performing StandardScalar like this

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

#Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan]})

#Get the index of null values
null_values = d['col1'].isnull()

#Perform standard scalar on only non-NaN values
df.loc[~null_values, ['col1']] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.loc[~null_values, ['col1']])
```

**Output**

```
    col1
0   -1.728498
1   NaN
2   -0.832240
3   -0.384111
4   NaN
5   0.064018
6   0.512148
7   NaN
8   0.960277
9   1.408406
10  NaN
```

Then fill nan values using [df.fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df.fillna(-1)
```

**outout**

```
    col1
0   -1.728498
1   -1.000000
2   -0.832240
3   -0.384111
4   -1.000000
5   0.064018
6   0.512148
7   -1.000000
8   0.960277
9   1.408406
10  -1.000000
```

Comment: You have shared some guides on how to handle missing data but in my case 
 I know what I want to do. I just want to assign them to -1 (As I have mentioned in my question) after (Not before) performing StandardScaler. My Question was simple that how I can do it?

Comment: Just one last question. Can this somehow be applied to Multidimensional DataFrame? e.g if we have a col2 also?

Comment: This can be applied but the way you slice the data for the null values and standard scalar would be different

Comment: if possible can you give an example?